Why does nix-shell with glib not provide proper .h files?
I am trying to use nixOS to build a gtk4 application that requires glib. When running a nix-shell with the following shell.nix:
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
  pkgs.mkShell {
    nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs.buildPackages; [
    libgcc
    glib
    clang-tools
    ];
}

And the following main.cpp:
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>

int main(){ }

Running g++ main.cpp returns
/nix/store/f8y44c3k32piprp8wj999cdlakpz86kz-glib-2.80.2-dev/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32:10: fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #include <glib/galloca.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Also, another dependency (shumate) seems to expect the header file #include <glib.h>, but glib in a nix-shell seems to instead provide #include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
How can I correctly use glib in a nix-shell for development? Thank you

You might need to explicitly specify the directories for headers packages.
example:
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    glib
    clang-tools
    ];
  
  # Add additional environment variables if needed
  NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE = [ "-I${glib.dev}/include" ];
  NIX_LDFLAGS = [ "-L${glib.lib}" ];

  # Set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include pkg-config files for glib during build
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH = "${glib.lib}/pkgconfig";
}

The -I${glib.dev}/include flag ensures that the compiler can find the Glib headers;
The -L${glib.lib} entry ensures that the linker knows where to look for the libraries;

According to nix-shell, glib is an undefined variable:
error: undefined variable 'glib' at /home/myaumyau/Projects/glib-issue/shell.nix:9:31

Humm, if it's saying "variable", maybe you need to add: let glib = import <nixpkgs/lib/glib> {};

This still doesn't work - at /home/myaumyau/Projects/glib-issue/shell.nix:14:3: error: file 'nixpkgs/lib/glib' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)
